# How do I get rid of a big pack file in my git repo?

Tags: git, github

I have a git repo with just one branch, where a coworker pushed some big files on. After I remove the big files, the repo is ~200MB, but the git folder is still 1.3GB because of a huge .git/pack folder.

What I tried so far (based on other answers from SO, but which do not seem to help me):

- **The BFG tool** -> I got rid of the big files, but the pack folder is still 1.3GB
- **git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch BIG_FILES' --prune-empty** -> I successfully rewrote the history, the big files are not mentioned in the historical commits anymore on the github website
- **git repack -a -d -f --depth=250 --window=250** -> Does not make the pack smaller
- **git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive** -> As an alternative to git repack, but does not work any better
- **git for-each-ref --format='delete %(refname)' refs/original | git update-ref --stdin** -> To no avail
- **The git clone file:// trick where I locally clone the repo, and which should remove spurious refs** -> Still, the pack is 1.3GB

What would be the next step?

Comment: `git filter-branch` should work as long as you `clean`-afterwards. It's not clear from your question why that wasn't successful.

Comment: do you mean clean `git clean` of some sort, or are you referring to repack/gc?

Comment: The right order is: (1) remove refs/original/, (2) reflog expire, (3) gc.  In theory 1 and 2 should be able to go in any order but step 3 definitely needs to happen last.  However, if you did the clone last, that should also work.

Comment: If you do a fresh clone from github, is it also that big?

Comment: @Roman: yes. Anyway, I was limited in time, so I removed ALL history and started with a fresh, small repo.

Comment: @torek: thanks, that's for future reference

Answer (score 0):

## PLEASE READ ME CAREFULLY!

> yes I know this topic is 4 years ago but I just read it today(17 Dec 2020)

## I did this for myself and it is work for me but it is may or may not work for you

### to me

the "history" is not a problem but my problem is the "pack" file
which has the size too much over the project file
(I just want to keep my vim config as in the .7zip format
the .7zip file is only 40 MB but the history file was 500 MB
which is the big problem for me when I try to pull it back to new setup machine
on my bad slow internet connection) so that's why SIZE is a matter for me

---

### so if you do this you will lose ALL of the history that you have done with your project

---

**what I did is :**

1. open the terminal(I'm using manjaro 20) `cd to-my-project-folder` then `rm -rf .git`
2. run `git init` (this repo I use to have 3 branchs `master , desktop , laptop`)
   now I run `git checkout -b main`  to create new branch call main and do some edit on
   file `README.md` save file then type `git status` you will see some untrack file
   now add them  `git add .`  to add everything then commit the change
   `git commit -m"your message here"`  then run  `git push -u origin main`
   just push to the new branch that we have been create.
3. go to your git repo then change the default branch (in my case was master) to
   the new branch that I just created then I delete all the branch(master,desktop,laptop)
   as I am using main as my default branch now
4. back to the terminal if I want master branch back I run `git checkout -b master`
   and I do some edit README.md file then `git add .` follow by `git commit -m"push message here"` 
   follow by `git push -u origin master` so now I have a branch master
5. back to the browser I just switch from branch main to master as a default branch

**That's all** of what  I did and it is work for me but as I mention you will lose all of the history

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to do this would be to download that branch remove everything you don't want and make another repository. Otherwise if you have access to the github you can go and manage the file there. But the best solution in my opinion is to download it and make a clean new branch without any chance of having cached file or anything.

Comment: This will lose all your version control history.